# phpMyAdmin use HTML code highlighting for values for TEXT column

Tags: phpmyadmin, syntax-highlighting

Is there way to enable HTML code highlighting for `TEXT` data type column when you insert/edit row of table.

Something similar to how phpMyAdmin highlights code when you select table and click `SQL` tab where you build SQL query.

Add-on solution is okay.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search finds this: http://stevensoule.com/chrome/SNTX/

phpMyAdmin uses CodeMirror for the SQL highlighting, it's probably very possible to extend it to highlight textareas, although how useful that would be to the average user is debatable. Feel free to open a feature request at https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/new though.